# The continuity of the function on $\mathbb{R}$: $I(y)=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^1sgn(x-y)\,dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, continuity

Investigate the continuity of the function on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$I(y)=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^1\text{sgn}(x-y)\,dx $$

I have some ideas:

1. Considering $[a,b], \, \forall b>a>1$. Then, $\text{sgn}(x-y)=-1, \forall (x,y) \in [0;1]\times[a;b]$.

$\qquad$So, $I(y)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, or $I(y)$ is continuous at all point $y>1$.

2. Prove similar, $I(y)$ is continuous at all point $y<0$.
3. ***On $[0;1]$***, I don't know how to prove.

Comment: minor detail, but just curious, is there a distinction you are making between $[a,b]$ and $[a;b]$?

Comment: I would look at $I(y+\delta) - I(y)$ to get some thoughts going.

Comment: You got answers for all your question posted to far – is there a reason that you *never accepted* an answer?

Comment: The remark of @Martin R is important: for many different reasons, you **have to** check ( = click on the green check sign) the better answer you have received. You can wait for that one or two days if you have doubts... This doesn't prevent to click on the up arrow of any of the answers you consider as good enough.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see your comment. I have already accepted answers on my posts..

Comment: @CSquared: I think both $[a,b]$ and $[a;b]$ are correct, because a, b are characters. In my country, the decimal point is a comma "," and some other countries, it's a dot "." For example, we write 0,5 instead of 0.5. So, we write $[0,5;0,6]$ instead of $[0.5,0.6]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I know the answer I am going to give looks a sledgehammer for killing a fly.

My intention here is to show that there exists higher level concepts/tools/properties that, even if you have not already met them can radically change the point of view. Anyhow, it is tools that you will meet in the coming year(s) if you study Calculus at a higher level, in particular in connection with Fourier/Laplace transforms.

The form of the integral (and as well the graphical representation) call for using convolution.

Indeed, your integral can be written under the form:

$$I(y)=\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}Rect(x)\text{sgn}(x-y)\,dx=-\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}Rect(x)\text{sgn}(y-x)\,dx$$

where $Rect$ is the characteristic function of interval $[0,1]$

($Rect(x):=1$ if $x \in [0,1]$, $0$ otherwise).

With appropriate notations:

$$I=- Rect \star sgn$$

Such a convolution is known to be continuous but let us prove it by using (once more) new tools/properties. The derivative of a convolution product can be obtained by convolving with one of the derivatives of its components (the other one remaining unchanged):

$$(f \star g)'=f \star g' \ \text{giving here} \ I'=- Rect \star sgn'=- Rect \star 2 \delta$$

Where the $2 \delta$ factor accounts for the sudden jump of intensity $+2$ at $x=0$.

As Dirac $\delta$ in neutral for convolution:

$$I'=-2 Rect$$

a property that can help you to build the curve (in a revese way, you can verify that the derivative is $-2$ on [0,1] and zero elsewhere).

In fact, we have to take an integration constant equal to $1$ because the value $I(0)=1$ can be computed dierectly on the integral definition.

Answer (score 2):

$$
I(y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
1, & y \leq 0 \\
\int_0^y (-1)dx + \int_y^1 dx = 1-2y, & 0 < y \leq 1 \\
-1, & y > 1 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

This function has 2 points of possible discontinuity: $y = 0$ and $y = 1$.

$$
\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow -0}I(y) = 1 = \lim\limits_{y \rightarrow +0}I(y).
$$

$$
\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 1-0}I(y) = -1 = \lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 1+0}I(y).
$$

This means that $I(y)$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok guy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier under the form

$$I(y)=\int \limits_{-y}^{1-y}\text{sgn}(x)\,dx.$$

The antiderivative of the sign function is continuous, as is the antiderivative of any piecewise continuous function. And the difference of two continuous functions is continuous.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach: For $y_1 < y_2$ set $a = \min(y_1, 0)$ and $b = \max(y_2, 1)$. Then
$$
 0 \le I(y_1) - I(y_2) = \int_0^1 (\underbrace{\operatorname{sgn}(x-y_1)-\operatorname{sgn}(x-y_2)}_{\ge 0}) \, dx \\
\le \int_a^b (\operatorname{sgn}(x-y_1)-\operatorname{sgn}(x-y_2)) \, dx
= \int_{y_1}^{y_2} 2 \, dx = 2(y_2-y_1) \, .
$$

Comment: Nice answer : continuous because "Lipschitzian".

Answer (score 0):

It should easy enough to obtain an explicit form for $I(y)$ by considering all $y \in \mathbb R$ and three cases:

1. $y < 0$ which implies $x-y > 0$;
2. $y > 1$ which implies $x-y < 0$;
3. $0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1$, and in this case divide the integral into $[0,y]$ and $[y,1]$.

Then just examine $I(y)$ when $y=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good solution.